# making heavy post request with angular 1.4 to express js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, express

I need to post some heavy request from client to server. my client is angular and I am making this request:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/myUrl',
  data:heavyArray
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        showSuccess();
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        showError();
      });
```

I am using express to get the data:

```
app.post('/myUrl', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.heavyArray;
    // ...
});
```

I have two problems:

1. the  request is very very slow, I thought of breaking up the array to chunks and send to the server by updates. but I cant find tutorial to do so.
2. the max length of the request is not enough. I set `app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));` 
   but I need more. can you help me?

Comment: What is source of this big array?

Comment: does it matter? I cant minimize it. the source is objects that describe something

Comment: Curious why you  need to send them all at once is why. You are asking for help and without knowing the workflow it's hard to offer alternatives. Maybe you can change workflow on updates or maybe you need chunked upload

Comment: thats my question how do i make a chunked upload